# Counting RecordType records

Tags: soql, aggregate, count

I am using simple_salesforce in Python3 to send `query_all()` SOQL queries against the REST API.

Now:
`sf.query_all('SELECT Id FROM RecordType')` returns 53 records.
But:
`sf.query_all('SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM RecordType')` returns the value 261.

What is the explanation for this?

I discovered this behavior after pulling the full SF objects into a data lake via the BulkAPI and the recordtype counts do not add up against the `count()` queries (only for recordtype so far).

Thanks,
R

Comment: Do you get the same numbers if you execute both queries in the Salesforce Developer Console?

Comment: Wow, I can actually confirm this is happening as well in Workbench (using the `query()` API call, not `queryAll()`). When I run this query `/services/data/v46.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+RecordType`, I get 2 records. However, when I run this query, `/services/data/v46.0/query?q=SELECT+Count(Id)+FROM+RecordType`, I receive a count of `4`

Comment: @BryanAnderson Interesting. When I run the first query, I get 117 records, and when I run the second query I get a count of 117. I wonder why you both would be getting different results. Do you get the same disparity if you execute the query directly?

Comment: @NicholasSavini when you say "directly", what do you mean by that?

Comment: @BryanAnderson Sorry, I meant just executing in the Dev Console or in the SOQL Query section of Workbench, rather than through the Rest Explorer. I'm curious to see if the issue has to do with the REST API or if something else is happening.

Comment: @NicholasSavini yes I just tested in Workbench via the `SOQL Query` window and I got the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from the Master RecordType being counted using `SELECT Count(Id) FROM RecordType` but not being returned when using `SELECT Id FROM RecordType`. It is Salesforce standard functionality that causes this to occur. For every sObject that you configure RecordTypes, you will have +1 results when performing the Count(Id).

I currently don't see a way to discriminate and eliminate such results using SOQL (via DeveloperConsole, Workbench or any REST query) but in Apex you can leverage the RecordTypeInfo class to identify if the record type id you are seeing on a record is master using `isMaster()`
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I anticipated something like that and wanted to document this behavior and make sure there is no bug anywhere.